# How to implement unix ls -s command in C?

Tags: c, unix

I have to write a program in C which returns file size in blocks just like ls -s command.
Please help.

I tried using stat() function (st_blksize)...And I am unable to implement it.

#### My code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DIR           *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    struct stat    buf;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        dp = opendir(".");
    }

    if(dp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Cannot open directory ");
        exit(2);
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
        if (stat(".", &buf))
        printf("%d ", buf.st_blksize);
    }

    closedir(dp);
    exit(0);
}
```

---

It is giving error buf size is not declared. Don't know what is the problem.

#### Addition

Thanks for the correction. I included the `<sys/stat.h>` header file. Now it is giving a warning:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__blksize_t’
```

I am new to C so can't make out what should be the possible solution.

Comment: you need to be more specific - and to try before to ask

Comment: What part are you having trouble implementing?

Comment: Please add the homework tag, and explain what you have tried so far, otherwise your question will probably closed.

Comment: I couldn't construe any other reason than homework for being required to do such a thing, so I added the [homework] tag.

Comment: *"I am unable to implement it"* is a monumentally unhelpful explanation of where you are stuck. What *are* you doing, and how *does* the result differ from what you expect?

Comment: I would imagine that `stat(".", &buf)` is incorrect and you would prefer something more like `stat(dirp->d_name, &buf)`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the correct header:

```
#incude <sys/stat.h>
```

That declares the structure and associated functions.

Note that `stat()` returns zero on success, so your test needs changing (and, as @jsmchmier pointed out in a comment, the call to stat should probably use `dirp->d_name` rather than the string literal `"."`).  Also, `st_blksize` is the size of the disk blocks, not the size of the file - that is `st_size` (measured in bytes).

POSIX says:

> `off_t st_size`           For regular files, the file size in bytes. 
>                           For symbolic links, the length in bytes of the 
>                           pathname contained in the symbolic link.
>
> `blksize_t st_blksize` A file system-specific preferred I/O block size 
>                           for this object. In some file system types, this 
>                           may vary from file to file.
>
> `blkcnt_t st_blocks`     Number of blocks allocated for this object.

Note that old (very old) versions of Unix did not support `st_blksize` or `st_blocks`.  I expect most current versions do.

---

> Now it is giving a warning..warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__blksize_t’

The chances are that `__blksize_t` is an unisgned integer type similar to `size_t`.  I'd probably use a simple cast:

```
printf("Block size = %d\n", (int)buf.st_blksize);
```

Alternatively, if you have C99 available, you could use the facilities from `<inttypes.h>` to use a bigger size:

```
printf("Block size = %" PRIu64 "\n", (uint64_t)buf.st_blksize);
```

In practice, this is overkill; the block size is unlikely to exceed 2 GB this decade, so `int` is likely to be sufficient for the foreseeable future.

Comment: If you are relying on `uint64_t` then you need C99; in which case you have `unsigned long long`, with the `%llu` format specifier, so you might as well use that (which is *at least* as big as `uint64_t`).

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, and stat/fstat it. The struct field st_blocks should contain the information you want. If you're dealing with a directory, use opendir, readdir, closedir (posix)... Just pointers to start your work.

EDIT

Add unistd.h and sys/stat.h. Then remember that stat return 0 on success, so

```
if (stat(dirp->d_name, &buf) == 0)
```

and I've changed "." to the name of the "element", which is what you wanted, I suppose. Another change is to use `st_blocks` and not st_blksize, which says how big is each block (e.g. 1024 or 4096 or...), and -s returns the size in number of blocks, not the size of a block.

The fragment of code is of course incomplete: if you pass an argument, dp is not initialized and even `dp == NULL` can fail, you shoud have nullified it before:

```
    DIR           *dp = NULL;
    struct dirent *dirp = NULL;
```

Comment: The `ls` command does not open files - nor should its replacement.

Comment: The user's original post talked about just "like ls -s", not specifying he wanted a clone of `ls`, but just that he needed the info "returned". He could use fstat if he's already opened the file for whatever reason. If you prefer read my words like: Open the file and fstat or stat it... Btw, between opendir, readdir and closedir I should've put stat, otherwise here one can think I believe that opendir-readdir is enough to get files' struct stat... Later he posted the code, I am going to take a look at it now

Answer (score 1):

From `man 2 stat` on my Mac OS X box:

```
NAME
     fstat, fstat64, lstat, lstat64, stat, stat64 -- get file status  

SYNOPSIS  
     #include <sys/stat.h>  

     int
     fstat(int fildes, struct stat *buf);
```

Note the `#include <sys/stat.h>` which you have not done. No doubt the actual layout of `struct stat` is defined in there, which is what your compiler is complaining about.

This is one aspect of the man pages which is not always discussed with beginners but is *very* useful indeed: the whole unix API is documented in them. Oh, it is not always the easiest place to find a function when you know what it should do but don't know what it is called, but *all* the answers are there.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, one bug in your code is that `dp` points to garbage and is only initialised if `argc` is less than 2, but you still try to use it in your `while` loop and you also try to `closedir` it. If you invoke your application with any arguments at all, it will probably crash.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warning, change the %d to %ld in the line: printf("%d ", buf.st_blksize);